# type mismatch found at 'EMPTYPE' between FETCH cursor and INTO variables

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
create or replace type emp_obj as object(empno varchar2(500));

create or replace type  emp_table as table of emp_obj ;
```

Procedure

```
create or replace procedure getempid(emptype out emp_table)
is
cursor c1 is select empno from emp ; 
begin 
open c1;
fetch c1 bulk collect into  emptype;

close c1;
end;
```

I am unable to understand why i am getting below error :

> Error(6,17): PLS-00386: type mismatch found at 'EMPTYPE' between FETCH cursor and INTO variables

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your cursor query is selecting a scalar value `empno` but tyring to bulk-fetch it into an object table. You’re expecting Oracle to figure out how to convert the scalar value to the object.

For a single-attribute object that might not look entirely unreasonable, but think of the complications for multi-attribute objects, or if you wanted the cursor to select a mix of object and scalar values. (As an aside, is your `empno` really a 500-char string, not a number?)

You can modify the cursor query to explictly construct an object instead:

```
select emp_obj(empno) from emp
```

So this version compiles:

```
create or replace procedure getempid (emptype out emp_table)
is
  cursor c1 is select emp_obj(empno) from emp;
begin 
  open c1;
  fetch c1 bulk collect into  emptype;
  close c1;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you cannot directly assign a collection object using a `bulk collect into` fetch from a cursor, notwithstanding the fact that the two would contain compatible datatype elements.

From oracle documentation,

> **PLS-00386**: type mismatch found at 'string' between FETCH cursor and
>   INTO variables
>
> Cause: An assignment target in the INTO list of a FETCH statement does
>   not match in datatype with the corresponding column in the select list
>   of the cursor declaration, and it is unclear which implicit conversion
>   is required to correct the mismatch.

Use element-wise assignment instead, using an intermediate collection.

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE Getempid(emptype OUT EMP_TABLE)
IS
  CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT empno
    FROM   emp;
  TYPE c_rowtype
    IS TABLE OF c1%ROWTYPE;
  crow C_ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    OPEN c1;

    FETCH c1 bulk collect INTO crow;

    CLOSE c1;

    FOR i IN 1..crow.count LOOP
        emptype(i).empno := crow(i).empno;
    END LOOP;
END;
```